# Error on findViewById - Subsampling Scale Image View - Android

Tags: android, image, zooming, scale, subsampling

I'm trying to test the code in this tutorial "Subsampling Scale Image View" to make a zoom image pinch, but it gives one error on .findViewById(id.**imageView**); - **cannot resolve symbol**..

My XML layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <com.davemorrissey.labs.subscaleview.SubsamplingScaleImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

And on my `MainActivity` fragment code have this code (inside onCreate method):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        SubsamplingScaleImageView imageView = (SubsamplingScaleImageView)findViewById(id.imageView);
        imageView.setImage(ImageSource.resource(R.drawable.abc));

    }
}
```

Can any one please help me, please?

thanks in advance
CAFC

Answer (score -4, accepted):

**Quick solution:** Replace `id.imageView` with `R.id.imageView`.

What happens is, when you want to reference an ID, you go to the `R` (Resources) directory provided by android. You have to go to the resources directory (`R`), and then in there there's the `id` directory. Then there's your id. So, the final result is `R.id.imageView`.

Comment: -6 downvotes... Wow

Comment: I have no clue why they downvoted this answer 6 times. Upvoted it, what a load of bs.

Answer (score -1):

```
 SubsamplingScaleImageView imageView = (SubsamplingScaleImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        imageView.setImage(ImageSource.resource(R.drawable.abc));
```

You have missed `R.id.imageView`